# ブラウザゲーム上で自作のドット絵フォントを表示する方法

Tags: javascript, html, css, font

HTML、CSS、JavaScript でドット絵のゲームを作ろうとしているのですが、相手のPCにないフォントを表示する方法がわかりません。ライブラリはp5.jsを使っていて、他にライブラリを使う予定はないです。

Answer (score 0):

`loadFont()` が有ります。

- [リファレンス](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont)
- [実行例](https://editor.p5js.org/2sman/sketches/hiYpXWxt0)
- [日本語記事](https://qiita.com/bit0101/items/9193d13f4b2abf8cd661)

これの内部では CSS の [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) が使われています。